# Upgrade manager doesn't finds ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade

I have 13.10 installed and would like to upgrade to 14.04. How would be this possible? If i do it like the manual says then i can update only to the devel version of ubuntu which i would like not.

Comment: already did that way but it is not really helping it still shows the developement version of ubuntu 14.04 and not the final release

Comment: checking option "Any new version" and after trying to search. 
do-release-upgrade with the -d option, "It could not calculate the space" error, but it was the developer version too.

Comment: try switching your update manager source to main or US servers, I guess it is just a matter of time before update got copied to all mirrors and you can pick it up.

Comment: The meta-release file hasn't been updated yet due to infrastructure issues on Canonical's end. Therefore, nothing will get picked up by the update manager.

Comment: Ahmadgeo that's something i thought of too, but no success still the same
@saiarcot895 good to know that, so i will have to wait now right? i assume there's nothing to do about it by our end.

Comment: Nothing to do but wait.

Comment: okay, thanks for the information, it would be nice of some of you would post a comment or answer to this if the meta file is finally updated

Comment: I guess @saiarcot895 has answered it :), you will have to just wait.

Comment: The meta-release file has been updated for non-LTS upgrade options (Trusty isn't listed in the LTS release file yet). Assuming you are running 13.10, can you try now?

Comment: @saiarcot895 i tried it right now, and it's working now, it detected the new version of ubuntu 14.04 trusty thar (not the dev one). Thanks for all the help and info's about this.